# How to create bean of Java class ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to create the following bean bean

```
 <bean id="couchBaseExecutor" class="java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor">
        <constructor-arg name="corePoolSize" value="10"></constructor-arg>
 </bean>
```

but it fails with the exception

```
13:48:24.206 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer - ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file [class java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor], probably due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet - unable to determine constructors/methods parameter names
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null
```

Does anyone have any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core Java classes don't have debug symbols/parameter metadata, so Spring can't determine the name of the constructor arguments. In that case, you have to use the index attribute with value 0 for the first constructor-arg, like this:

```
<constructor-arg index="0" value="10"/>
```